# addProximityAlert not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, locationmanager

I'm trying to use addProximityAlert. I've followed the tutorial from this site http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.dk/2012/10/proximity-alerts.html.
I've also tried other tutorials but I couldn't get them to work either.

This is my code for creating the proximity alert:

```
double lat = 55.659890;
double longi = 12.591188;
float radius = 3000;

lm = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("dk.itu.percom.tourguide.android.ProximityAlert");
long expire = -1;
proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, intent, 0);

lm.addProximityAlert(lat, longi, radius, expire, proximityIntent);
```

This is my receiver:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String k=LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        boolean state=intent.getBooleanExtra(k, false);
        if(state){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to my Area", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Thank you for visiting my Area,come back again!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }
    }
}
```

And my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="ProximityIntentReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="dk.itu.percom.tourguide.android.ProximityAlert" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And I've added the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have also tried to add the receiver with

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("dk.itu.percom.tourguide.android.ProximityAlert"); 
registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
```

But that doesn't work either. Somewhere I also read that using -1 for expiration doesn't work with 4.3 and you instead should use a very high number, but no luck with that either.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Android officiel doc ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)) you'll find this sentence "***Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired***"

what is that mean? it means when you are testing your app on the AVD and u send a gps coordinates(latitude, longitude) from the DDMS to AVD its really hard to simulate the real aspect of a gps, (because in the first place u pick some point to be your proximPoint and just after that you choose anthor point very far from the proximPoint to see if its work) and thats not what it's happing with a real device.

so the solution is to test your app on a real device or with the DDMS try to change the coordiantes very slowly until you are in the zone wanted.